# Replace image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace an image with another image.

Since the webpage, that i'm building, has to be viewable in IE8, then CSS based solutions played out quircky.

I tried the

- display: none; and display: block; trick
- opacity: 0; and opacity: 1; trick

But they both don't function as I want to (centered inside a div, because IE8 plays some stuff differently, then I thought that may-be a simple src="" swaping will do the trick.

I started with jquery, but since I'm pretty bad with understanding the $(this) and DOM, then it isnt working at all, but i think I got my logic right.

**So, HTML is here:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="#">
    <img class="original" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200">
    <img class="overlay" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
</a>
…
…
```

So I have numerous a tags inside a wrapper, each containing two images. As they are responsive and having the same ratio, then no sizes are needed.

**And my started jquery:**

```
$('.wrapper a').hover(

function () {

    var original = $(this).attr('src');    
    var overlay = $(this).next().attr('src');

    $(this).children('.original').attr('src', overlay);
}, 
function () {

    $(this).children('.original').attr('src', original);
}
);
```

And here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHyh6/4/) .

So, I'm really after this, that each a tag I have inside a wrapper would change the image according to the images inside of that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply show `overlay` image on hover and hide `original` image

```
$('.wrapper a').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.original').toggle();
    $(this).find('.overlay').toggle();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.original').toggle();
    $(this).find('.overlay').toggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hHyh6/9/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript here at all. Really. Use CSS:

```
.wrapper a:hover .original {
    display: none;
}
.wrapper a:hover .overlay {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hHyh6/10/

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can try this:

```
$('.overlay').hide();  //<----------first hide the overlay image
$('.wrapper a').hover(function () {
   $(this).find('.overlay').show().add(this).find('.original').hide();
   // here find the overlay and show it and hide the original
}, function () {
   $(this).find('.overlay').hide().add(this).find('.original').show();
   // here find the overlay and hide it and show the original
});
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle using `.end()`](http://jsfiddle.net/hHyh6/7/)

#### [Demo @ Fiddle using `.add(this)`](http://jsfiddle.net/hHyh6/11/)

Answer (score 0):

try this js i also tried in your fiddle too it works

```
var current_cash;
$('.wrapper a').hover(

function () {

    current_cash = $(this).find('.original').attr('src');    
    var overlay = $(this).find('.overlay').attr('src');

    $(this).children('.original').attr('src', overlay);
}, 
function () {

    $(this).children('.original').attr('src', current_cash);
}
);
```